# What Gets Added to `document`?

Tags: html, forms

I was working on a page and noticed they had an element bound to `document` (ex. `document.formNameId`).  I was thinking it must be the JavaScript and not being able to find a place where it was set, I removed all the JavaScript on the page.  I still found the element name set on the document.

After playing with it, it seems `form` elements that have a name attribute set are added to `document`.  Are there any other elements that are by default bound like that?

## EDIT:

Upon further inspection, you can even find elements inside that form element by the same API.

So if I do something like this to get an input element: `document.formName.inputName`

[Check this example out.](http://jsbin.com/acihun/1/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are called (in HTML5) [Named Properties](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#dom-document-namedItem-which)

The description in the spec says:

> The Document interface supports named properties. The supported
>   property names at any moment consist of the values of the name content
>   attributes of all the **applet**, exposed **embed**, **form**, **iframe**, **img**, and
>   exposed **object** elements in the Document that have non-empty name
>   content attributes, and the values of the id content attributes of all
>   the applet and exposed object elements in the Document that have
>   non-empty id content attributes, and the values of the id content
>   attributes of all the img elements in the Document that have both
>   non-empty name content attributes and non-empty id content attributes.
>   The supported property names must be in tree order, ignoring later
>   duplicates, with values from id attributes coming before values from
>   name attributes when the same element contributes both.

So these happens for a number of elements. There is also a description at the above link of how the values of such properties are determined, including how for forms, it becomes the list of controls on the form.

Comment: Wow, ok.  It's weird, I'm working on JavaScript that's super old, so I guess this worked for a while (found a script tag that specified "JavaScript1.1").

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document has a good overview over all properties and methods of the `document` object.

[obsolete: `document.formNameId` is missing there and I could not find it on this website, so it seems it is not a default property but was added by a script (a quick google search for "document.formnameid" lists only this stackoverflow question).]

Comment: I had a form with both the name and id set to get it appended to `document`.  After messing with it, it appears it's the `name` setting on a form.  [Look at this example.](http://jsbin.com/iqimif/1/edit)

Comment: I see, I thought it was literally "formNameId". The second paragraph is obsolete then, but the link from the first one may have some useful information.

Comment: Yeah, I'll take a look at it.  I scanned through it and didn't see any specific information on element names being added, but I'll take a more thorough look later.